# Get starting and ending date of react calendar

Tags: reactjs, calendar, react-big-calendar

I am using `"react-big-calendar": "^0.20.3",`

Currently i am using `getDrilldownView={(targetDate, currentViewName, configuredViewNames) => this.updateDate(targetDate, currentViewName, configuredViewNames)}`props on component to get start and end time in big calendar react js. I feel like this is not good way to get start and end date and i could not find it on documentation too.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vw3wlm63y

what i want is 2019/1/27 as start date and 2019/3/2 as end date

and `onRangeChange` gives both start and end date when view or date is changed but i want it when the page loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using

```
this.startDate = moment().subtract(1, 'months').endOf('month').startOf('week').format('YYYY/MM/DD');
        this.endDate = moment().add(1, 'months').startOf('month').endOf('week').format('YYYY/MM/DD');
```

and it worked
to get the start and end date of current calendar view for first load. I think there is not inbuilt method to get details.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with react-big-calendar and I solved it with:

```
const start = moment().startOf('month').startOf('week').format('YYYY/MM/DD');
const end = moment().endOf('month').endOf('week').format('YYYY/MM/DD');
```